How to return multiple list in a python return statement
I've a python block like this. And I want to return 2 lists in the return statement.
I currently have return trade_result_list + blotter_result_list, but this shows an error "Expected type 'list[TradeResult]' (matched generic type 'list[_T]'), got 'list[BlotterResults]' instead " in the line where return statement is present.
Not sure what's wrong here. Any help is much appreciated.
@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=False, order=False)
class TradeResult:
  trade_ids: Optional[list[str]]
  aIds: Optional[list[int]]
  statuses: list[str]
  messages: Optional[list[str]]


@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=False, order=False)
class BlotterResults:
  trade_id: str
  s_id: Optional[int]
  portfolio_id: Optional[int]
  ptxn_type: Optional[str]


class ExcelReportCreator:
  def __init__(self):
     pass

  def _correlate_results(self, ptxn_match_results: List[PtxnFinderResult],
                       ptxn_match_results_blotter: List[PtxnFinderResultForBlotter]) -> 
    List[Union[TradeResult, BlotterResults]]:
    trade_result_list: list[TradeResult] = list()
    blotter_result_list: list[BlotterResults] = list()
    results_list_for_blotter_and_bulk: List[Union[TradeResult, BlotterResults]] = 
    list()
    trade_id_list = []
    a_Id_list = []
    status_list = []
    status_msg_list = []

    for record in ptxn_match_results:
        for txn_record in record.txn_record.get('records', []):
            external_pks = txn_record['recordBody']['externalPks']
            trade_id = next((pk['value'] for pk in external_pks if pk['key'] == 
            'tradeId'), None)
            trade_id_list.append(trade_id)
            a_id = next((pk['value'] for pk in external_pks if pk['key'] == 'aId'), 
            None)
            a_Id_list.append(a_id)
            status = txn_record.get('status', None)
            status_value = status[0].get('status')
            status_list.append(status_value)
            message = status[0].get('message', None)
            status_msg_list.append(message)

    trade_result_list.append(TradeResult(
        trade_ids=trade_id_list,
        aIds=a_Id_list,
        statuses=status_list,
        messages=status_msg_list
    ))

    for i, r in enumerate(ptxn_match_results_blotter):
        cur_result: PtxnFinderResultForBlotter = r
        if cur_result.txn_record is not None:
            s_id = cur_result.txn_record['sId']['id']
            portfolio_id = cur_result.txn_record['portfolioId']['id']
            ptxn_type = cur_result.txn_record['type']
        else:
            s_id = None
            portfolio_id = None
            ptxn_type = None
        blotter_result_list.append(BlotterResults(
            trade_id=cur_result.trade_id,
            s_id=s_id,
            portfolio_id=portfolio_id,
            ptxn_type=ptxn_type
        ))
    return trade_result_list + blotter_result_list

def create_report(
        self,
        config: ConfigValues,
        report_file_name: str,
        ptxn_match_results: list[PtxnFinderResult],
        ptxn_match_results_blotter: list[PtxnFinderResultForBlotter],
        trade_file_name: str,
        ptxn_invalid_rows_list: list,
        invalid_rows_result: Union[int, list[InvalidTradeRunDetails]]) -> Path:

    trade_result_list: list[TradeResult] = self._correlate_results(
        ptxn_match_results=ptxn_match_results,
        ptxn_match_results_blotter=ptxn_match_results_blotter)


return the two lists as a tuple: return (trade_result_list, blotter_result_list)

return trade_result_list + blotter_result_list returns one list, created by concatenating those two lists together. If you want to return multiple values, you separate them with ,, not +.

But the type annotation says it only returns one list: -> List[Union[TradeResult, BlotterResults]]

Did you mean -> List[TradeResult], List[BlotterResults]?

You can only return one object but that could be, or example, a Tuple of Lists or a List of Lists. A Tuple is convenient because you can then use code along the lines of a, b = my_method()  to access the returned Lists.

Thank you. Actually I want to return 2 lists. Doesn't this type annotaion -> List[
Union[TradeResult, BlotterResults]] return 2 lists? If not, any other way to return 2 lists?

@Ram no. that type annotation specifies a single list. Note, you can only return a single value. That value could be a container, like a tuple, though

Ok, mind showing me the code that'll return a container?

Your _correlate_results return type hinting says you are returning list, with items either of type TradeResult or BlotterResults. But, in function call itself you are expecting to see a list with instance of type TradeResult only. Please have look to this line of your code:
trade_result_list: list[TradeResult] = self._correlate_results(
        ptxn_match_results=ptxn_match_results,
        ptxn_match_results_blotter=ptxn_match_results_blotter)

You can fix it by changing type hinting like this:
trade_result_list: List[Union[TradeResult, BlotterResults]] = self._correlate_results(
        ptxn_match_results=ptxn_match_results,
        ptxn_match_results_blotter=ptxn_match_results_blotter)

But, it will be misleading, since trade_result_list will contain items of both instances: TradeResult and BlotterResults.
Instead, since the first item of your returning list is TradeResult you can do the following:
trade_result: TradeResult
blotter_results_list: List[BlotterResults]
trade_result, *blotter_results_list = self._correlate_results(
        ptxn_match_results=ptxn_match_results,
        ptxn_match_results_blotter=ptxn_match_results_blotter)

Note: your trade_result_list in _correlate_results function contains only one element, so there is no need to encapsulate it into list, but if you still want, you can always do the following: trade_result_list: List[TradeResult] = [trade_result].
If you want to return multiple separate lists, please use the techniques suggested in the comments or @chepner's answer, but also don't forget to change trade_result_list type hinting in function call line to be corresponding, like this:
trade_result_list: List[TradeResult]
correlated_result: List[BlotterResults]
correlated_result: tuple[List[TradeResult], List[BlotterResults]] = self._correlate_results(
        ptxn_match_results=ptxn_match_results,
        ptxn_match_results_blotter=ptxn_match_results_blotter)
trade_result_list, blotter_result_list = correlated_result



The return statement that returns two lists would be
return trade_result_list, blotter_result_list

a tuple consisting of the two lists.
The correct type hint for the function using this return statement would be
def _correlate_results(self, 
                       ptxn_match_results: list[PtxnFinderResult],
                       ptxn_match_results_blotter: list[PtxnFinderResultForBlotter]
    ) ->  tuple[list[TradeResult], list[BlotterResults]]:

